# Qt Virtual Keyboard's InputPanel is blank on Raspberry Pi 0

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

The Qt I'm using was cross complied on Windows and followed the instruction from https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS .

I added InputPanel into my qt project and I'm using the code from [basic-b2qt](https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/blob/5.11/examples/virtualkeyboard/basic/basic-b2qt.qml#L106) with only minor changes.

And I can use this keyboard on Windows.

[image: Windows]

But, when I test it on my raspberry pi and focus on some inputs, the InputPanel shows up, but only the top part is normal. The bottom part where the keys should be placed is totally blank. I can only see the black background but no any key.

I'm wondering what may involved in this issue. At least where should I start to debug this. There should be something wrong, but I cannot find any problem or warning in the qt creator's output.

InputPanel:

```
Binding {
    target: VirtualKeyboardSettings
    property: "fullScreenMode"
    value: true
}
InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    z: 89
    y: 320
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    states: State {
        name: "visible"
        when: inputPanel.active
        PropertyChanges {
            target: inputPanel
            y: window.height - inputPanel.height
        }
    }
    transitions: Transition {
        id: inputPanelTransition
        from: ""
        to: "visible"
        reversible: true
        enabled: !VirtualKeyboardSettings.fullScreenMode
        ParallelAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "y"
                duration: 250
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reason, but `qmake install` seems not copy/add/contain the layouts that required by qt virtualkeyboard.

There should be a better solution, but you can copy the layouts to some places and set layout path manually.

```
    Binding {
        target: VirtualKeyboardSettings
        property: "layoutPath"
        value: "file:///home/pi/layouts"
    }
```